# Employee Self Service in OFBiz

Tags: erp, ofbiz

I am looking into OFBiz HR module, there leave functionality is implemented perfectly. But i am not understand few points. Even if i login as demoemployee i can apply leave for Admin.
This sould not be the case.

Please verify the following steps:

1. Logged in as demoemployee: (uid: demoemployee, pwd:ofbiz)
2. Navigate to HR --> Human Resources --> Leave
3. Click on "New Leave" button
4. Select partyid as "admin" The Administrator, and other fields... and click on "Create".
5. The leave has been created for admin.

I want to know how to restrict employee to apply his/her own leaves.

Is ofbiz can be used for Employee-Self-Service functionalities like updating his own details/viewing his own salary details, updating his own leavs....

Thanks,
Chandrasekhar K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually OFBiz OTTB components are pretty generic and will not apply to everyones use case and some customization is required, this is also the case with HR module.

> I am looking into OFBiz HR module, there leave functionality is implemented perfectly. But i am not understand few points. Even if i login as demoemployee i can apply leave for Admin. This sould not be the case.

demoemployee is part of HUMANRES_EMPLOYEE group which has VIEW and CREATE permissions, that's why with this user you can view and create leaves. But notice that you don't have UPDATE permission for example, so you cannot update and approve the leave. Usually in this case the leave is still not valid, only entered in the system…

> I want to know how to restrict employee to apply his/her own leaves.

To restrict the users from creating leaves for other users, you have to override the humanResManagerPermission service and apply your custom logic (logged in user partyId should be the same as leaving party Id)

> Is ofbiz can be used for Employee-Self-Service functionalities like updating his own details/viewing his own salary details, updating his own leavs....

Yes definitely, two approaches:

1. if there are some screens in HR or Party component close to your requirements customize them
2. Create a new component, with the spcific screens you want.

In both cases you can/should reuse the existing datamode and services. Most/all of the work will be about creating appropirate UI